Add Black Bars to Expand Resolution
I have images that are 768x1200, and I want to add black bars to them so that their resolution is 1920x1080. How do I do that?

Create a new image, 1920 x 1080 px, fill it black. Paste your image on top, reposition/rescale as required.

It can be done by a ton of programs so you need to decide which one you want to use.
Always keep a backup for the original files.
You can use free software for this. In Irfan View (windows) https://www.irfanview.com/
You have two options. Add both, vertical and horizontal bars, which will render a small image inside a big black background, but that is probably not what you want.

Most likely you want to maximize the size of the image and then add bars. So it is a two-step process.

Menu > Image > Resize/Resample
On the dialog box keep an eye on these options. Method, Preserve aspect ratio.
I am typing the height value, so the with is still inside the limits of the file I want.



Menu > Image > Change Canvas size

On this dialog box define Method 2, and the final size. Choose the bar's color and center.

Those basic steps can be done in any image editing software.

If you want to process a ton of images, in Irfan view:
Menu > File >Batch Conversion Rename

Choose Conversion, Output directory, File format, etc.
Add the files you want to convert
Use Advanced Options for Bulk Resize

And on that dialog box do the same as I explained. Resample first.

And make a second pass to add the bars.

